# Git client that has a interactive graph, which allow drag&drop and copy&paste nodes?

Tags: git

Just a random idea that can up to my mind serveral times when using git.

Apparently quite some git features can be implemented as gui graph operation:

- `branch`: click a plus button next to parent node.
- `cherry-pick`: select a branch till the leaf, copy and paste to parent node.
- `rebase`: select a branch till the leaf, drag and drop to parent node.
- `checkout`: double click a node

Are there git clients that have implemented these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/FredrikNoren/ungit/ is very close.
It doesn't use the exact gestures you describe, e.g. you can't drag a branch to rebase, but you can click it to select and see possible rebase (and other action) targets, activated by a 2nd click:

[image: screen recording of a rebase]

(rebase specifically only works on currently checked-out branch — a requirement of the underlying `git` CLI it runs — so you may need to double-click the branch you want to rebase first.)